# Adding Profile to Google Analytics using API with C#

Tags: c#, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I wish to use the method specified here:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/profiles/insert

I've tried to work it out by looking at some guides here: http://www.daimto.com/google-analytics-api-v3-with-c/ and http://www.arboundy.com/2012/04/getting-started-with-google-analytics-in-c/ but in truth I'm completely lost and can't seem to get close.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I have been trying to get that to work for a while now.  Its not in any of my tutorials because I haven't been able to get it to work.  I just sent an email off to one of the Google Devs, asking him for some info on what we need to send to get it to work.  I tried sending everything I can think of though the Query Explorer and nothing works  https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/analytics/v3/analytics.management.profiles.insert

Comment: 2 downvoters and no comment why?

Comment: @DaImTo, I've made some progress on this. I'll edit in with some code tomorrow. It seems like the insert function returns an authorization error saying the function is not available. I searched the specifics of the error and it seems that some functions in the api are in beta and you have to be whitelisted for them to work. Will be more precise tomorrow when back in work.

Comment: Downvotes are likely because a) you don't say whats wrong, or ask a specific question b) you don't post your code.

Comment: @user2025312 I was wondering if maybe it was only available to professional GA accounts.   I just think its weird that they don't mention in the documentation that you have to be whitelisted.  If they have a try it section you should be able to try it yet that doesn't work either.   I sent another mail off to the devs asking if you needed to be whitelisted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write operations are still in beta.  Before you can access this feature you need to request access to the beta.

> Write operations in the Management API (e.g. create, update, delete,
>   patch) for Web Property, View (Profile), and Goal resources is
>   currently available as a developer preview in limited beta. If you're
>   interested in using these features,  [request access to the beta](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtProfileGuide#limits).

Comment: That's the conclusion I had come to aswell, but that's the only page I've seen the whitelisting aspect confirmed. Thanks a lot for the link. I've requested my project to be whitelisted now.

Comment: Let me know if it works :)  BTW it takes around 24 hours to get access to the Real-time API beta.

Comment: @DalmTo - Unfortunately still no response from google yet. Once they reply and I've checked it works I'll probably add an answer here with the full steps I took w/ code and such.

Comment: If its anything like the Real-time API beta, you wont get a reply it will just start working.  Try it.  :)

Comment: Thanks I'll keep trying it. No success yet, I sent a second request through, maybe it'll land in someone elses inbox and go through.